# rsync daemon max connections unlimited

Tags: rsync

I'm creating a gui app to upload files to a particular place on a server.

the user is able to drop files and these files are 'moved' to the server, if the file already exists, then it is only updated as the transfer is over the internet.
So Im basing this app on a rsync daemon.

I've seen it is possible to set the "max connections" parameter in rsyncd.conf to unlimited
but.. is this good practice? what happens if a user drops 100 small files, like text files, or small jpg images... or even more, like a digital camera image folder containing 500 images..

Would all these transfers start at the same time?

This sounds like a bad thing, but is it really?

I could do :

A) throttle the uploads from the gui app and only let 10 files go at a time or so.

B) Group all the files on a drop and send them with 1 rsync request, rsync would queue them automatically, one file would be uploaded at a time, there are as much connections as drops, I cannot imagine someone dropping hundreds of times.

But is this necessary, again, is is 'wrong' to have many many connections?